# Zigzag traversal of a two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, traversal

I need to traverse a two-dimensional array in a zigzag and pick the elements along the way:

From:

```js
[['','','',''],
 ['','','',''],
 ['','','',''],
 ['','','','']]
```

To:

```js
['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','']
```

My approach was to use a for loop, check each index of the first array and compare it against the index of the next array and then if that number is bigger by one push it into the new one dimensional array.

What is the best approach to solve this? Do you have some resources to learn more about this pattern?

Comment: Good one, wait I will try to do. can array contains duplicate entries?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Do you really think that your accepted answer is correct?

Comment: @Alan You asked zigzag method. right?

Comment: yes, zigzag method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLD ANSWER:

you can use `.flat()` method for `javascript` array. [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let array = [
    [1, 3, 4, 10],
    [2, 5, 9, 11],
    [6, 8, 12, 15],
    [7, 13, 14, 16],
]
const flatArray = array.flat()
flatArray.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
console.log(flatArray)
```

UPDATE ANSWER:
after question update output

```js
const items = [
    [1, 3, 4, 10],
    [2, 5, 9, 11],
    [6, 8, 12, 15],
    [7, 13, 14, 16],
];

/*const items =  [
  [ ,  ,  ,  ],
  [ ,  ,  ,  ],
  [ ,  ,  ,  ],
  [ ,  ,  ,  ],
]*/

function zigZag(arr) {
    let array = []
    const itemCounts = arr.reduce((pre, cur)=> pre+cur.length,0)    
    for(let i=0; i<itemCounts; i+=1){
        let round = []
        for(let j=0; j<arr.length; j+=1){
            if(arr[j].length){
                round.push({
                    value: arr[j][0],
                    row:j
                })
            }
            
        }
        const minValue = Math.min(...round.map(item=>item.value))
        const target = round.find(item=>item.value == minValue)
        array.push(arr[target.row].shift())
    }    
    return array;
};

console.log(zigZag(items))
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you for telling about a `flat` function.

Comment: but what this is doing is just sorting the array in increase order, the challenge here is to order the array based in the zig zag way

Comment: @Alan oh, zigzag way. ok but from your output it's not zigzag I think. your output is correct?

Comment: yes, you are right the input and output can be confuse, I change it to give a better understanding of the question

Comment: @Alan thanks, it's better. I'll update my answer and notify you

Comment: @Alan my answer is update, just use number values for answer

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

This function will merge arrays in zigZag way.

Here I have shown example with 2 arrays with different data type values.

```js
function zigZag(array) {
    let arrayLength = array.length;
    let arrayItemLength = array[0].length;
    let result = [];
    let flag = true;

    for(let i = 0; i < (arrayLength + (arrayLength / 2) + 1) ; i++) {
        if(i < arrayItemLength) {
            let length = (i + 1);
            let ii = i;
            for(let j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if(flag == true) result.push(array[j][ii]);
                else result.push(array[ii][j]);
                ii-=1;
            }
        }else {
            let ii = (i + 1) - arrayItemLength;

            for(let j = arrayItemLength - 1; j > i - arrayItemLength; j--) {
                if(flag == true) result.push(array[ii][j]);
                else result.push(array[j][ii]);
                ii+=1;
            }
        }
        if(flag == true) flag = false;
        else flag = true;
    }

    return result;
}

let array = [
    ["" , "" , "" , "" ],
    ["" , "" , "" , "" ],
    ["" , "" , "" , "" ],
    ["" , "" , "" , "" ],
];

let array_1 = [
    [1, 3, 4, 10],
    [2, 5, 9, 11],
    [6, 8, 12, 15],
    [7, 13, 14, 16],
];

console.log(zigZag(array)); // icons
console.log(zigZag(array_1)); // numbers
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Try this, I think this what you want to do.

```js
let array = [
    [1, 3, 4, 10],
    [2, 5, 9, 11],
    [6, 8, 12, 15],
    [7, 13, 14, 16],
];

function mergeArray(array) {
    let merged = array.reduce((item, total) => [...total, ...item], []);
    return merged.sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

let result = mergeArray(array);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: but what this is doing is just sorting the array in increase order, the challenge here is to order the array based in the zig zag way

Comment: @Alan Actually your question is good, but don't know why someone had downvote you too.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to transform a *n×n* array such as:

```js
[ ['', '', '', '']

, ['', '', '', '']

, ['', '', '', '']

, ['', '', '', ''] ]
```

into:

```js
['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','']
```

Let's transform the original array into a "matrix of positions" and let's try to picture the "zigzag":

```js
[ [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3]]
// ↙      ↗      ↙      ↗
, [[1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3]]
// ↗      ↙      ↗      ↙
, [[2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3]]
// ↙      ↗      ↙      ↗
, [[3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]]
// ↗      ↙      ↗      ↙
]
```

If we focus on the edges we can start working out a pattern:

```js
[ [0,0]
, [1,0], /* … */ [0,1]
, [2,0], /* … */ [0,2]
, [3,0], /* … */ [0,3]
, [3,1], /* … */ [1,3]
, [3,2], /* … */ [2,3]
,                [3,3] ]
```

Now we need to work out all the `[x,y]` between each edges and traverse each edge in opposite direction:

```js
const inp1 = zigzag([ ['', '', '', '']

                    , ['', '', '', '']

                    , ['', '☝️', '', '']

                    , ['', '', '', ''] ]);

const inp2 = zigzag([ ['', '', '']

                    , ['', '', '']

                    , ['', '☝️', ''] ]);

const inp3 = zigzag([ ['', '']

                    , ['', ''] ]);

const inp4 = zigzag([ [''] ]);

console.log(`
  [${String(inp1)}]
  [${String(inp2)}]
  [${String(inp3)}]
  [${String(inp4)}]
`);
```

```html
<script>
const zigzag = inp => {
  const m = inp.length - 1;
  const edges = [];
  for (let x = 0; x <= m; x++) edges.push([x, 0]);
  for (let x = 1; x <= m; x++) edges.push([m, x]);
  return edges.flatMap(([x, y], i) => {
    const path = [[x, y]];
    for (let a = x, b = y; a != y && b != x;) path.push([--a, ++b]);
    return (i % 2 ? path : path.reverse()).map(([x, y]) => inp[x][y]);
  });
}
</script>
```